# In MySQL, can you translate string of values from one column to corresponding values from another column?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have data in a table "people" structured like this:

```
userid   | fname      | lname       | favfruit
----------------------------------------------
001      | Joe        | Blow        | banana
002      | Jim        | Crow        | orange
003      | Bozo       | Joe         | grapes
004      | Mo         | Fo          | lemon
005      | Back       | Hoe         | peach
006      | Barack     | O           | peach
007      | J          | Lo          | grapes
008      | Yo         | Lo          | lemon
009      | Hell       | No          | orange
010      | Steve      | Jobs        | apple
```

Now I'm given a string of several userids:

```
007,001,009,003,010
```

Is there a single MySQL query that will return a string of the corresponding favfruits?:

```
grapes,banana,orange,grapes,apple
```

My alternative is to query the table in a loop for each userid, which seems EXCESSIVE:

```
<?
$string = "007,001,009,003,010";
$userids = explode(",",$string);
foreach($userids as $id) {
  $query = "SELECT favfruit FROM people WHERE userid='$id'";
  $res = mysql_query($query);                    <-- deprecated, i know.
  $fruits[] = mysql_result($res,0,"favfruit");   <-- just to illustrate. :)
}
$newstring = implode(",",$fruits);  // = grapes,banana,orange,grapes,apple
?>
```

Is there a better (single-query) method?

Comment: You could use `in`. `where  userid in ($string)`. If `$string` is user input parameterize that though..

Comment: thanks chris85. that helps determine if a value is present in the comma-separated string, but it doesn't translate to a corresponding column.

Comment: You pull the column in the `select` list, or am I misreading this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the correspondence between `userid` and `favfruit`, my preferred way is to concatenate them in the result.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(',', CONCAT(userid, ':', favfruit) AS users_and_fruits
FROM people
WHERE userid IN ('007','001','009','003','010');
```

This will return a string like:

```
007:grapes,001:banana,009:orange,003:grapes,010:apple
```

You can then explode this and explode each item to get the correspondences.

If you don't want this, and just want a list in the same order as the original, use `ORDER BY FIELD`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(favfruit ORDER BY FIELD(userid, '007','001','009','003','010')) AS favfruits
FROM people
WHERE userid IN ('007','001','009','003','010');
```

In all these queries, make sure you quote the user IDs, because leading zeroes on numbers are discarded and they won't match correctly (or change your `userid` column to `INT`).

Comment: i think you nailed the problem, @Barmar. I was using one comma-separated string in the order-by-field rather than individually-quoted strings separated by commas. now the hassle will be translating one to the other ('x,y,z' --> 'x','y','z'). i'll try your preferred method too. thanks!

Comment: got it! the userid column is already INT. i just had to drop the quotes altogether: `ORDER BY FIELD(userid,007,001,009,003,010)` did the trick.

Comment: If it's INT, how does it show up with leading zeroes when you show the table contents?

Comment: the table in my original question isn't the real table i'm working with, but if the real table DID show up with leading zeroes in that INT column, i think ZEROFILL would be the reason, right? is that what you mean? for what it's worth the userid string in my real app excludes leading zeroes, so it really looks more like `ORDER BY FIELD(userid,7,1,9,3,10)` where  the userid column is INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL.

Comment: didn't know about the zerofill option

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(favfruit
                ORDER BY favfruit ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS favfruit
FROM people
WHERE userid IN (007,
                 001,
                 009,
                 003,
                 010);
```

You can `ORDER` this `BY userid`. Just replace the `favfruit` by `userid` into `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily keep the order though, in case that is important.

Comment: wow, that was fast, md. and it worked! good point about order, joachim. any way to account for that?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, is correct. It doesn't keep the order.

Comment: i think i solved the order problem by appending this to the query: ORDER BY FIELD(userid,$string). i'll run some tests, but does that sound right?

Comment: @JoshR, If you really need to keep the order, that is also possible here.

Comment: i DO have to make sure the order matches so that (in my example), steve jobs doesn't get matched up with an orange or banana. :)

Comment: I've modified the query. Now it keeps order. :)

Comment: `ORDER BY favfruit` doesn't tell you which fruit goes with which userid.

Comment: @JoshR If you can use your `order by field...` in the GROUP_CONCAT order by, it should work.

Comment: yeah, ORDER BY favfruit ASC just returns a string alphanumerically sorted by favfruit. my ORDER BY FIELD method also failed, but i'm not sure why. will try your suggestion, joachim!

Comment: @JoshR The arguments to `FIELD` have to be strings. If you give numbers, it will convert them to strings, but the numeric representation loses the leading zeroes. See my answer.

Comment: You can `ORDER` this `BY userid`. Just replace the `favfruit` by `userid` into `GROUP_CONCAT`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT favfruit FROM people where userid in (007,001,009,003,010);
```

@Md Mahfuzur Rahman's answer will return a single string. This one will return a result set of each fruit.

Comment: I think he needs a single string. In his code, he is using this `$newstring = implode(",",$fruits);`.

Comment: thanks @gremash. that provides the right fruits, which could easily be made into a string, but not in the corresponding order.